# About publish an application in Local IIS

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I'm going to publish my Application in my Local IIS .But I have some Question before i Publish.
The Question is

1. If I host my application can I access my Application any system
       in my local area Network?
2. Can I run the application
           with out opening visual studio and run through visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IIS : Internet Information Services

1. Yes if you deploy application,for sure you can access within your network.
2. Yes, If successfully deployed there is no need to open visual studio to run your application , as it is deployed already

Comment: Thanks you .Is there any other advantages ?

Comment: IIS acts as a server for deploying without which you cannot host your app locally

Comment: If I host my application from Location D:Drive after that I moved  my application to F:Drive .what will happen? Does it work?

Comment: No , if files are moved from the location then how come it will work?

Comment: After I published ,If add another form to my application what should i do? what should i do?Should i republish it again ?

Comment: Yes you have to re-publish with those files

Comment: I must accept it ,thanks you very much and nice to talk to you. Can you provide me a good link to follow publish and republish an application in IIS

Comment: what version of visual studio using?

Comment: While deploying websites it may not behave always as tutorials are given ,we have to deploy and tackle real time scenarios,for a quick tuto u can refer : http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/deployment/visual-studio-web-deployment/deploying-to-iis